# Create Struts2 tag inside JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, struts2

I would like to know if it is possible to create a Struts2 tag (e.g.  ) inside a JavaScript function or using jQuery.

For instance, I tried:

```
function createStrutsTag(){           

        var newElement;
        newElement= document.createElement("div");
        newElement.className = 'newer';
        newElement.innerHTML = '<s\:textfield label="HELLO" \/>';              

        newElement.css('visibility','visible'); }
```

However, it just created the div containing the label < s:textfield label="HELLO" /> without being parsed to its real meaning.

I also tried with **struts2-jquery-plugin tags** (sj) which also crashed...so I would like to know if it can be done or I should create those elements in the HTML part of the body, being hidden by CSS style and then show or hide them using JavaScript /jquery functions as they are needed by the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS is executed on the client. JSP tags are evaluated on the server.

You have several options, not limited to:

**Use the output of the text tag as a JS value**

There are at least two ways to do this:

- Put the JS in a JSP, or
- Evaluate your JS via the JSP processor

**Evaluate *some* JS in the JSP and call the external JS**

For example, you could create a hash of I18N labels etc. in your JSP and pass it to JS functionality that lives in a JS file (where it *should* live).

**Store the output of the text tag in a hidden DOM element**

Retrieve it using JS and construct your DOM as you are now.

This is arguably the cleanest.

---

**Rough overview of "clean" solution using jQuery**

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/nmHjB/) for the basics.

**JSP:**

```xml
<div id="hello" style="display: none;"><s:text label="HELLO" /></div>
```

**JS:**

```js
function createDiv() {
  var $div = $("<div className='newer'>").html($("#hello").html());
  $("#outputHere").html($div);
}
```

It could be tightened up a bit, but that's the general idea.

Comment: For the moment, I just included the JS in a JSP. I made it work by creating the text tag inside the JSP with visibility:hidden. Then, inside the JS function I just turn its visibility to visible. However, this is not really the answer to my question :S    Please, could you provide a simple example of the cleanest method?? Thanks.

Comment: Could be possible to edit the content of the struts tag depending of any other variable from the JS domain? or just I can do this with fixed content? Thanks for your quick answers and fiddle.

Comment: @aloplop85 I'm not sure what you mean by "edit the content of the Struts tag". Again: tags are evaluated *on the server* before the client has seen the response, thus before the client could do anything affecting the tag itself via JS.

Comment: +1... @aloplop85 the clearer is the question, the better are the answers... you can do anything with Struts2, even creating your own components, but nothing will ever let you handle them from JS (client) once the page is processed (on the server).

Comment: Also, if you knew how the tags are processed by the server you could change any of its properties, couldn´t you? (e.g. $($div[0].children[0]).css("color","red");  )

Comment: @aloplop85 Yes, but that would be extremely brittle. Instead you should use id and/or class attributes.

Comment: I tried with id and class attributes and works perfectly (for some tags) from JS. If it does not work, you may try to substitute the struts tags for the equivalent HTML code (e.g. using Firebug). Thanks you again.