# Unable to create Struts2 tags inside JSP script tag

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have some javascript inside the `<s:param>` tag on a JSP page.

I want to create a struts2 tag given a certain condition is true. Here is what I have:

```
<s:param name="pageScript">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      if(translateField === "true") {
        var declaredValue;
        declaredValue= document.createElement("div");
        declaredValue.innerHTML = '<s\:textfield label="HELLO" \/>';              
      } else {
        var declaredValue = document.createElement("input");
        declaredValue.type = "text";
        declaredValue.id = "declaredValueInput";
        declaredValue.value = "some value";
      }
  });
  </script>
</s:param>
```

I followed the comments on this page: [Create Struts2 tag inside JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817775/create-struts2-tag-inside-javascript-function) and I have my JS within a JSP inside a struts tag.

Anyone see what I may be doing wrong, or if there is a better way to go about this?

I am using a textfield as an example, but in the end I want to create a `<s:select>` tag.

**To clarify exactly what I want to do:** I am trying to dynamically create a  element if a flag is set to true basically. So if the flag is true, create a  tag that uses a list in my struts class, otherwise use a plain ol' textfield.

I was using a text field in my example just to see if I can get a struts tag to work.

Comment: JS in s:param tag?

Comment: Why not use a simple <s:if> to check your boolean?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @AleksandrM I am trying to create a struts element dynamically via JScript based on a flag.

Comment: Can you just show / hide an appropriate element?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the answer you've linked:

> JS is executed on the client. JSP tags are evaluated on the server.

It means that, when the Javascript engine of the browser starts to read that piece of Javascript, there's no trace of the Struts tags anymore, because they've been translated into HTML code long before the page has been rendered.

You could inject a Struts tag into JS with the proper syntax, that would be

```xml
declaredValue.innerHTML = '<s:textfield label="HELLO" />';
```

, then you would have the problem that the generated HTML would not be *sanitized* to be contained in a Javascript String (`'`, `"`, etc...). But is it what you really need ? Can't you simply store the `"HELLO"` text, and then build an HTML `<input type="text" />` on your own ?

Something like:

```xml
var text  = '<s:text name="HELLO" />';
```

or (remember to use `escapeJavascript="true"` in `<s:property />` tags inside JS blocks, or you'll be prone to XSS attacks):

```xml
var text  = '<s:property value='getText("HELLO")' escapeJavascript="true" />';
```

and then

```xml
var label = '<label for="hello">' + text + '</label>';
var input = '<input type="text" id="hello" />';
declaredValue.innerHTML = label + input;
```

should get you closer to what you're trying to achieve, I guess.

P.S: innerHTML is fast but is not the proper way to create objects in Javascript.

Comment: I am trying to dynamically create a <s:select> element if a flag is set to true basically. So if the flag is true, create a <s:select> tag that uses a list in my struts class, otherwise use a plain ol' textfield.